# Getting each anchor value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to build a list of emails from a webpage that is formatted like so:

```
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="email-popdown">
    <a href="mailto:sue@domain.com">sue@domain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv">
  <div class="email-popdown">
    <a href="mailto:mark@domain.com">mark@domain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv">
  <div class="email-popdown">
    <a href="mailto:jane@domain.com">jane@domain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript that isn't working:

```
$('.email-popdown').each(function(i, obj) {
    $('body').append($(this).child('a').attr('href') + '<br>');
});
```

Any help getting this to list emails as:

```
sue@domain.com
<br>
mark@domain.com
<br>
jane@domain.com
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [.child](https://api.jquery.com/child/), and `.replace("mailto:", "")` to strip of `mailto:` from `href`.

```js
$('.email-popdown').each(function(i, obj) {
    $('body').append($(this).find('a').attr('href').replace("mailto:", "") + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="email-popdown">
    <a href="mailto:sue@domain.com">sue@domain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv">
  <div class="email-popdown">
    <a href="mailto:mark@domain.com">mark@domain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="somediv">
  <div class="email-popdown">
    <a href="mailto:jane@domain.com">jane@domain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find() instead of child()

```
$('.email-popdown').each(function(i, obj) {
    $('body').append($(this).find('a').text() + '<br>');
});
```